# EF 4.3 & CodeFirst: One-to-many navigation properties loads as nulls without entity proxy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, code-first, entity-framework-4.3

Problem is next - i have 2 entities with one-to-many relationships:

```
public class Schema
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid SchemaId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string ElementName { get; set; }

    public List<Element> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ElementId { get; set; }

    public Guid SchemaId { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Schema InSchema { get; set; }
}
```

and project referenced to EntityFramework v4.3 package.
After storing some Schemas with related Elements in database I load Schemas list (for example, var schemasList=context.Schemas.ToList()). After this in all instances of Schema in Elements property values is null. Now i solve this problem with adding dynamic proxy for entities, but this have some bad impact in numerous dev scenarious (e.g. saving may cause "Entity tracking by multiple context" error).
Thank for any help with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used .Include in your query?

ie

```
from s in Schema.Include(sc=>sc.Elements)
select s;
```

note you will need

```
using System.Data.Entity
```

to use include

Comment: it's necessary with CodeFirst?

Comment: @DrAlligieri: Depends, I had one server where I didn't need to type that and another one where it was required to type that. Required a walk through the Business Layer. In any case, this is required as otherwise you would be doing lazy loading (only loading what is needed), so now you say with an Include that you have to **JOIN** in the Elements table (which can be considered a performance impact if you didn't need it).

Comment: OK, tnx for answer. I'm familiar with lazy loading concept (and not very like it;)). And another question - Include loads only sc.Elements (ak List<Element>) items (ak Element) simple properties or navigate too (if it have another complex List-like navigations props).

Comment: Include is absolutely necessary to load related entities; by default it loads the entire object from the database (so not really lazy loading...), but none of the related objects, except those you specifically request with Include.